# Authorization engine in java

Tags: java, authorization

In the course of my work i need to develop an authorization engine ( i'm already authenticated and i check access of a user to an action ) in order to store all the authorization logic inside a same place and be able to reuse it and i have created the mini library.

http://github.com/eltados/canny

what do you think about it?

Is there any lightweight Authorization engine library i could have a look at?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use Spring Security before I developed anything of my own.  Authorization and authentication are cross-cutting concerns.  Spring properly puts them in aspects that you can configure down to the method level.

Answer (score 3):

I only had a brief look and was wondering whether you had considered the following questions:

- I'm not a fan of using a static attribute to store the Authorisation object and all the rules, this could lead to problems in clustered environments or when multiple applications share an appserver (I'm thinking shared classloader problems with JBoss here)
- The canny engine provides no out-of-the-box functionality for dynamically accessing authorisation stores. As far as I can tell in order to get user/permission information from LDAP or a database, a custom rule needs to be created.
- I'm not sure whether having the definitions of the rules in code is the best place, as it will mean having to rewrite/rebuild/redeploy code to change the rules.

Note, maybe I have misunderstood some of the concerns, but the readme and test classes were a little bit sparse.

Personally, [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/) has been my Authentication/Authorisation framework of choice.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting opinion i have developed as a version simple Authorization engine ( really as a side project ) 

I'm not an experienced programmer I'm working in a single app single server environment so i never came across problems of clustered environment, I will try to investigate this and see how my code is problematic.

Canny does not support any out of the box authorization mechanism this is due to the fact that the project is really young, and the app i use already had a custom ( but badly designed user/permission system ) that i plugged into Canny but make no sense to release.

Comment: In code definition of the rules make sense in the environment in which i'm working, it is easier to implement for and more flexible but i will consider having a Xml definition of the rules ( even if i'm not a big fan of XML ).

The readme and test classes are quite sparse and i really appreciate you took some of your time to evaluate this project and came back with constructive answers

Comment: this mean idea was to have a Can method that you can use anywhere in your application and not have to worry about the implementation of the logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

Three years later... You want to use XACML and a XACML authorization engine. There are open-source alternatives (WSO2, Heras AF, Sun XACML) and vendors alternatives (Axiomatics, IBM...).

Disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics.

Our solution can be an authorization service or used as a library you embed within your application - see more at http://www.axiomatics.com/